# Does C# have built-in methods to convert string control characters to "normal characters"?

Tags: c#, string, control-characters

There is a `Char.IsControl()` method to *identify* such characters, but I want a way to convert them to "normal" characters.
i.e. some way to visualise a string that contains such characters. Probably similar to what Notepad++ does.

Obviously such a visualisation will be imperfect, and ambiguous ... but does it exist as a built in method?

Comment: What does Notepad++ do?

Comment: Control characters are usually characters below 0x20.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notepad++ is converting the control characters to the [control pictures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_control_characters#Control_pictures) U+240x and you'll also have to do that yourself. To convert `controlChar` to its visualization just use `controlChar + 0x2400` or `controlChar + '\u2400'`

```
Console.Write((char)(i + 0x2400));
```

[Demo on dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/S236ss). Output:

```
␀ ␁ ␂ ␃ ␄ ␅ ␆ ␇ ␈ ␉ ␊ ␋ ␌ ␍ ␎ ␏ ␐ ␑ ␒ ␓ ␔ ␕ ␖ ␗ ␘ ␙ ␚ ␛ ␜ ␝ ␞ ␟
```

You can also do like this

```
Console.Write(char.ConvertFromUtf32(i + '\u2400'));
```

Of course **this only works for the first 32 control characters** (and space), to convert the remaining ones you have to use a `Dictionary` or something similar because the code points aren't contiguous. For example 0x7F will need to be converted to ␡ ([U+2421](https://unicodeplus.com/U+2421)). There aren't any control pictures for the C1 control codes so you're out of luck for those. There are many other control codes above U+0080 and most of them don't have a control picture either

Comment: Hilariously ... Notepad++ doesn't have a renderer for those characters :D thye just show up as squares :D

Comment: @Brondahl that's a font problem and has nothing to do with Notepad++. Choose a different font with those characters. Notepad++ doesn't have very good font substitution/font replacement like many other editors

Answer (score 1):

```
var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
foreach (var character in input)
  {
   if (character.IsControl())
     stringBuilder.Append(Convert.ToInt32(character).ToString("X4"));
  }

 return stringBuilder.ToString();
```

Comment: this prints the code point of the control character, but it's not *what Notepad++ does*